# i need to take few elements from array - javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Javascript - as in title. My exaple:

```
var nawigacja = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];
nawigacja.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].className = 'navig';
nawigacja.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].className = 'navig';
nawigacja.getElementsByTagName('button')[2].className = 'navig';
nawigacja.getElementsByTagName('button')[3].className = 'navig';
```

Can I define classes for all of the tags?

Comment: Yes, use a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Loop_Statements).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a loop.

```
var buttons = nawigacja.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].className = 'navig';
}
```

Comment: And in case he only wants to edit the first four buttons: `Math.min(buttons.length, 4)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery Javascript Framework http://jquery.com/, you could do it easily like this :

```
$('nav button').addClass('navig');
```

Without it, you could do this :

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('nav');
list = list.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(i=0 ; i < list.length ; i ++) {
    list[i].className = 'navig';
}
```

Comment: There is no jQuery tag, this doesn't do the same thing which would be `$('nav button').removeClass().addClass('navig');`

Comment: Property names are case sensitive btw. It should be `className`.